# DOMDocument does not load a larger valid xml file

Tags: php, simplexml, domdocument

I use code like this

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml_source); 
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
```

And i get en error:

```
Warning (2): DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag ZverejnujeText line 34 in Entity, line: 273 [APP/Controller/RecordsController.php, line 43]
Warning (2): DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag StatnaPomocIneProgramyPodpory line 2 in Entity, line: 273 [APP/Controller/RecordsController.php, line 43]
Warning (2): simplexml_import_dom() [function.simplexml-import-dom]: Invalid Nodetype to import [APP/Controller/RecordsController.php, line 47]
```

When trying to load this [xml](http://e-pravo.sk/valid_large_xml.xml) (~110 kB)

And according to w3c validator, the xml is valid.

I have no problem loading [this](http://e-pravo.sk/valid_large_xml_2.xml) (~25 kB, but the same structure)

If i dont use DOM and i load the xml directly

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_source);
```

the same errors occurs.

Im lost at the moment, how can i solve this?

Comment: The information you give is wrong. The XML is not valid, read the error messages that are reported by `DOMDocument::loadXML()`. You need to fix the XML first. DOMDocument has no problems to read large and valid XML files anyway.

Comment: And with large I don't mean 110kB, more like 60 Megabyte and such ;)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp according to this it is syntactically valid and i cant spot any errors in the document. the tags it is complaining about are properly closed and nested if i havent overlooked anything

Comment: @RomanKoncek http://w3fools.com/

Comment: W3C doesn't have an XML validator.

Comment: i get different errors for that XML: http://codepad.viper-7.com/rRfwBP

Comment: interesting, i get the same error using load instead of loadXML as well (this error itself has no influence on functionality, so its ok)

Comment: probably the error is related to something else im going to investigate it, thanks

Comment: compare the xml in the string against the xml in the file. they are likely different.

Comment: yes i did and that was the problem :) i was storing the xml content to database (mysql type text) and it truncates anything above 65kB (i didnt know the limit is so low), thanks again

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question, according to OP data has been truncated by Mysql silently and OP so misguided by that then about the validity of the XML (the truncated XML was invalid XML as it is often the case).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you, but DOMDocument::loadXML() loads direct xml like DOMDocument::loadXML('<element>value</element>');
I guess you want to load the xml file and not a string,
I tried DOMDocument::load('hxxp://....../yourfile.xml');
That worked for me.

Hope this helps.
Grets, Nik